# How can JMS Point-to-Point Sampler be used in Jmeter to send messages to an IBM MQ queue

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq, jndi, point-to-point

I have a local IBM MQ instance set up with some default queues.

Using JMeter 5.4.1, I first want to send messages to one of these queues to test that the connection works.

**1. Is it possible with IBM MQ or does it only work with Active MQ?**

**The test scenario I wish to achieve is this:**

- JMeter sends some message with ID1 to a queue named "DEV.QUEUE.1"
- The System under test takes the message from "DEV.QUEUE.1", does some processing and places the response on "DEV.QUEUE.2"
- JMeter checks and asserts that a response has been received for the message with ID1 on the queue named "DEV.QUEUE.2" within X seconds
- View results in Aggregate Report

**2. Is this achievable with JMS Point-to-Point Sampler?**

I've checked the official JMeter documentation, but I don't understand what connection details I need to place in each of the sampler's configuration fields.

```
JMS Resources
QueueConnection Factory:
JNDI name Request queue:
JNDI name Receive queue:
Number of samples to aggregate
JMS Selector
....
etc...
```

[image]
I was able to connect to one queue and send messages using custom code in a JSR223 Sampler.
These are the connection details I have used to create the connection:

```
def hostName = "127.0.0.1"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

def connInboundQueue = cf.createConnection("mquser", "secretpassword")
def sessInboundQueue = connInboundQueue.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
def destinationInboundQueue = sessInboundQueue.createQueue(queueName)
connInboundQueue.start()
```

I'm guessing that I can map these connection credentials to this JMS Point-to-Point Sampler so that I can achieve the same connection, I just don't know how.

**So to sum up:**

1a. How can I achieve connection to my two queues using the JMS Point-to-Point Sampler?

2a. How can the JMS Point-to-Point Sampler be configured for the scenario I have described above?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible, the options are in:

1. Use [mqmeter - MQ JMeter Extension](https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter), it will provide a custom [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler
2. Continue with JSR223 Test Elements, example producer and consumer code snippets can be found in [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article